# detect and disable auto clicker apps

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha

we have an online game ,that some people made our life so difficult by cheating with the auto clickers apps
i think the apps are made with c++ or javascript , they save the settings in it and the app works like human playing !
i tried change input ids and names , controller classes name
but they keep passing it
i know captcha will solve the issue , but it will make the rest of the players leave the game ..

we need detect and block any one uses auto clicker without destroying the fun of the game
any ideas ?

Comment: Apply captcha only when dectect strange behavior.

Comment: Also recaptcha has an invisible option that only appears on bot detection. Just adjust the threshold to avoid being unfair with humans.

Comment: Can you put your game mechanic on a timed cool down that won't punish regular users but will delay auto-clickers?

Comment: Have a look at the `isTrusted` property of `event`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

Comment: what is the satisfaction of the people to play on that way? Why people have to play on that way? Maybe they are short passing something in the game that is not so useful as you think.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that sounds interesting (i didn't know it) but if is on client side you can trick it anyway, or not?

Comment: Most probably yes. But it will be harder a bit. Make changes and then [uglify the code](https://www.uglifyjs.net/)...

Comment: thank you all for your kind replies , i tried to make it very difficult to them to use but still they managed to pass tests , recaptcha i not a nice solution it always appears as the game work fast ,for the isTrusted , this is the first time i hear about it , can you explain how it works ? thanks a lot .